# Angular component styles

Tags: angular

I have a CSS class in the `style.css` which should apply to any components within my app. I have a component A that needs this class which works fine. And this component has another component B inside it which needs this class too. But this class won't work in this inner component B. Any ideas?

style.css:

```
.my-hover:hover {...}
```

component A:

```
....
<div class="my-hover"></div>
<app-component-b *ngIf="aCondition"></app-component-b>
```

component B:

```
<div class="my-hover"></div>
```

If I prefix my CSS class with `::ng-deep`, then this class will not work in A or B.

Comment: Maybe you have some conflicting css rules? This should work, as in this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5s9hhz

Comment: [CHECK WORKING STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hover-parent-child-styles), this should ideally work, do check if you have a `viewEncapsulation` property set to `none` in `component b`. Try to recreate your issue with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

This should work, as in this example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewfqqw .

You should check *angular.json*, you imported

```
 "styles": [
     "src/styles.css"
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject styles to child components from Host using this techniqe :

`:host >>> app-component-b div.my-hover{
   /* your style here */
   display: flex;
}`

refer this - https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/